# Birt: Where to put rptlibrary file in birt viewer?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, birt

I am using Mapit report library to get some google maps charts. It is working ok in designer but when I deploy the reports to birtviewer, the maps are not loading. I think the birtviewer is not reading the library files

I have put the library file in the following locations but it does not wrok

1) C:\Apache\webapps\Birt\

2) C:\Apache\webapps\Birt\scriptlib\

3) C:\Apache\webapps\Birt\WEB-INF\lib\

Birt is the home directory for the reports on birtviewer

In Windows->preferences->Report Design --> Resource

The path is `<Current Project Folder>`

I tried to put the library file directly under the project so that there is no confusion about the path. I tried to put the same library file in the birt home directory but nothing seems to work for me :(

[image]

[image]

Can someone please help me where to put the rptlibrary file BIRT Online Maps.rptlibrary in the birtviewer so that the report can read it and display the map

Regards

Arif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put it anywhere, but add it via Shared Resources. Example:

[image]

[image]

When you click at added library in Designer, you'll see that path is hardcoded. Make sure that you deploy rptlibrary on the same path at your runtime environment.

Comment: for testing purpose, I tried to open the report in tomcat via designer and added the library via shared resources. There are also few csv files being used that I added via shared resources. What I have found is that if I run the report in designer html, the reports runs fine but if I run it via birtviewer and browser, I get an error that org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.flatfile.InvalidResourceException: Invalid table name:data/\Zip Code Boundaries - Bay Area.csv
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.addException(ExecutionContext.java:1245)

Comment: all my source files and library files are under the data folder in the project folder. it works fine if I run it via designer but it does not work in browser and birt viewer. I tried to open the web.xml to see if any custom path has been set but its also empty

Answer (score 2):

Since you have left the resource path as default `<current project folder>`, **the root** of your resource path in the webviewer is `C:/Apache/webapps/Birt/`

But it does not work like a classpath, you have to reproduce **strictly the same relative path** as what you did in your eclipse designer: for example if this library is under a subfolder `<current project folder>/libraries/mapit.rptlibrary`, then you should reproduce the same with your deployment `C:/Apache/webapps/Birt/libraries/mapit.rptlibrary`

Path of resources is a common source of troubles with BIRT reports, i think it may be a good practice to set explicitely a resource path outside the scope of the webviewer through WEB-INF/web.xml, this makes upgrades easier and we have a better chance to understand what we do.

**EDIT:** It should work as you described it. I would not use spaces in the name of a library but i don't think it the reason of this trouble. Note you can dynamically display the resource path of a context from a report: create a dynamic text in the report with expression:

```
reportContext.getAppContext().get("birt.viewer.resource.path");
```

This might help to find out what's going on.

Comment: Under the workspace of Birt, I created a project Named Gold-Standard. Under this project, I have created a folder named CA. The report and the library file are both in CA folder. I have put the report in C:/Apache/webapps/Birt/ and I tried to put the library file in both C:/Apache/webapps/Birt/ and C:/Apache/webapps/Birt/CA/ but the birtviewer is still not reading it :(

Comment: I have edited the problem description above and included more detail about where the library file was in resources/designer and where I put them in Birtviewer

Comment: why don't you open report .rptdesign file under Tomcat path and through designer add rptlibrary from under Tomcat path. This way it'll gonna work for sure.

Comment: Because the development and deployment (birtviewer) are completely different machines and also the production server is a different machine. It won't be possible to add the path from designer this way I think?